# Integrate a Mac Computer on an Existing TortoiseSVN Repository

Tags: macos, tortoisesvn, repository

We're currently using TortoiseSVN for versioning our many websites. It's been only Windows users so far but we're adding another developer that uses a Mac. Is there a Mac program that will integrate with the TortoiseSVN repositories we already have?

Please do not reply with suggestions of SVN clients to use on a Mac. I am looking for a solution that works with an existing repository.

Comment: Any SVN client will be able to work with an existing repository. What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I was not aware of that. To be clear, is this what you're saying?: The repository itself is a standardized structure and that the program is just used to interface with it. In the end the repository will look and act the same regardless of which client is used.

Comment: More or less yes. Are you using a remote repository (via HTTP or SSH) or it is it on a file share?

Comment: It's on a local network server.

Comment: Ok but do you access it by http(s), ssh or you mount a file share?

Comment: TortoiseSVN is an implementation of a subversion client; the repository is still plain subversion so any subversion client will do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could work but accessing a repository via file share is **not recommended, highly discouraged, and unsupported**. From the [TortoiseSVN manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-share)l:

> Although in theory it is possible to put a FSFS repository on a
>   network share and have multiple users access it using file://
>   protocol, this is most definitely not recommended. In fact we would
>   strongly discourage it, and do not support such use.
>
> Firstly you are giving every user direct write access to the
>   repository, so any user could accidentally delete the entire
>   repository or make it unusable in some other way.
>
> Secondly not all network file sharing protocols support the locking
>   that Subversion requires, so you may find your repository gets
>   corrupted. It may not happen straight away, but one day two users will
>   try to access the repository at the same time.
>
> Thirdly the file permissions have to be set just so. You may just
>   about get away with it on a native Windows share, but SAMBA is
>   particularly difficult.
>
> file:// access is intended for local, single-user access only,
>   particularly testing and debugging. When you want to share the
>   repository you really need to set up a proper server, and it is not
>   nearly as difficult as you might think. Read the section called
>   “Accessing the Repository” for guidelines on choosing and setting up a
>   server.

In other words: don't. Set up a proper repository with access via SSH or HTTP and then any client will work.

Comment: Hook scripts also become fragile or completely broken as well. At best, they'll be unreliable.